# SQL: Select children and number of their children

Tags: mysql, sql

I want select children of category and count of theirs children.

Structure of **Category**:

```
Id  Parent   Name
0     0      main
1     0      Games
2     0      Books
3     2      Drama
4     2      Comedy
```

For id '0' it should return games 0, books 2. For id '2' it should return drama 0, comedy 0

How to do it?

Comment: which database platform are you using ?

Comment: select name, count(*) from Category where parent=? and id<>0 group by name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Id  Parent   Name
1     0      main
2     1      Games
3     1      Books
4     3      Drama
5     3      Comedy
```

If you add '0' value for the Main Row you can do this using a Simple Query. Main is a Parent of Book and Games so we had to use some other value for Main.

So After that you need to write a Simple Query

```
Select c1.name, (select count(id) from category c2 where c2.parent = c1.id) 
    as count from category c1  where c1.parent=1;
```

Thank you.

Comment: I want get childrens and count of THEIR (next level) childrens.

Answer (score 1):

Use inner join to fetch the data :

```
   SELECT c.Name, c.Parent
   FROM Category c 
   INNER JOIN Category p on c.id = p.parent
```

Answer (score 1):

This will return the expected result:

```
SELECT t1.parent, t1.name, COUNT(t2.id)
FROM vt AS t1 LEFT JOIN vt AS t2 ON t2.parent =t1.id
WHERE t1.parent <> t1.id
GROUP BY t1.parent, t1.name
```

But if there are additional levels of nested categories you need some kind of recursive query and then the syntax depends on your DBMS.

**Edit:**

I don't know about your actual rules how to count those categories, but when the number of levels is known (and small) hierarchies can be processed using multiple Left Joins.

```
SELECT t1.parent, t1.name, COUNT(COALESCE(t2.id,t3.id,t4.id))
FROM vt AS t1 LEFT JOIN vt AS t2 
ON t2.parent =t1.id
LEFT JOIN vt AS t3 
ON t3.parent =t2.id
LEFT JOIN vt AS t4
ON t4.parent =t3.id
WHERE t1.parent <> t1.id
GROUP BY t1.parent, t1.name
```

Comment: The problem is there are many levels. I think recursive query might be ok with few hundred categories.

Comment: What's your DBMS? Does it support recursion?

Comment: Ok, it's MySQL, so no recursion, depending on your needs it might be possible to add a new Left join for each level, i'll edit my post